# I can't run create line chart in Angular using D3, "property 'date' doesn't exist on type [number, number]"

Tags: angular, typescript, d3.js

I'm trying to run my first code using D3 and Angular. All the samples I've found so far on line kind of present something similar to the below code (in pure JavaScript).

I'm always getting the same error:

```
//property 'date' doesn't exist on type [number, number]
//property 'value' doesn't exist on type [number, number]
```

What am I missing?

And I'm always stuck at

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
import * as d3 from 'd3';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-intro-demo',
 templateUrl: './intro-demo.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./intro-demo.component.css']
})
export class IntroDemoComponent implements OnInit {
  rawData = [{ date: "10/25/2018", value: 1 },
  { date: "10/26/2018", value: 3 },
  { date: "10/27/2018", value: 0 },
  { date: "10/28/2018", value: 0 },
  { date: "10/29/2018", value: 5 },
  { date: "10/30/2018", value: 8 },
  { date: "10/31/2018", value: 7 },
  { date: "11/01/2018", value: 11 },
  { date: "11/02/2018", value: 23 },
  { date: "11/03/2018", value: 13 },
  { date: "11/04/2018", value: 15 },
  { date: "11/05/2018", value: 37 },
  { date: "11/06/2018", value: 32 },
  { date: "11/07/2018", value: 38 },
  { date: "11/08/2018", value: 42 },
  { date: "11/09/2018", value: 43 },
  { date: "11/10/2018", value: 21 },
  { date: "11/11/2018", value: 24 },
  { date: "11/12/2018", value: 50 },
  { date: "11/13/2018", value: 53 },
  { date: "11/14/2018", value: 59 },
  { date: "11/15/2018", value: 61 },
  { date: "11/16/2018", value: 62 }];

  margin = 50;
  width = 1024;
  height = 768;

  data = [];
  parseTime = d3.timeParse("%m/%d/%Y");

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.rawData.forEach(d => {
       this.data.push({ date: this.parseTime(d.date), value: d.value })
    });

    this.createChart();
  }

  createChart() {
     const svg = d3.select('#chart')
     .append('svg')
     .attr('width', this.width + this.margin)
     .attr('height', this.width + 2 * this.margin)
   ;

    const dataGroup = svg.append('g')
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + this.margin + ", " + this.margin + ")");

    // Add X axis --> it is a date format
    const x = d3.scaleTime()
       .domain(d3.extent(this.data, d => d.date))
       .range([0, this.width]);

    svg.append("g")
       .attr("transform", "translate(0," + this.height + ")")
       .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

    // Add Y axis
    const y = d3.scaleLinear()
       .domain([0, d3.max(this.data, function (d) { return +d.value; })])
       .range([this.height, 0]);

    svg.append("g")
       .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

    const line = d3.line() //
      .x(d => x(d.date))   //property 'date' doesn't exist on type [number, number]
      .y(d => y(d.value)); //property 'date' doesn't exist on type [number, number]

   // Add the line
   svg.append("path")
      .datum(this.data)
      .attr("fill", "none")
      .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
      .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
      .attr("d", line)

  }
```

Comment: Hi! seems to work fine, heres a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-d3-dummy-test) running your code, you sure about thats where the error comes from?

Comment: It looks like they were having the same issue in the following post that has a good answer in it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49981518/d3-property-x-and-property-y-doesnt-exist-on-type-number-number-in-angular-p?rq=1

Comment: @Joe, thank you so much.

Comment: sounds like @Joe hit the right issue here, are you importing typings mismatching the version of the d3?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [D3 property X and Property Y doesn't exist on type \[number, number\] in Angular Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49981518/d3-property-x-and-property-y-doesnt-exist-on-type-number-number-in-angular-p)